# Select an element from a List

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I displayed a list containing the list of employees I want when I select an employee their personell's informations personal information is displayed in their TextField I tried to do it but the department ( extracted from another table) and the age and gender are not displayed.
Here is the result:

[image]

```
 table = new JTable();
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            responsableTechnique=responsablesTechnique.get(table.getSelectedRow());
            nomResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getNom());
            prenomResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getPrenom());
            loginResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique   .getLogin());
            passwordResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getPassword());
            mailResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getMail());
            adresseResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getAdresse());
            fonctionResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getFonction());
             ageFormattedTextField.setText(responsableTechnique.getAge());
            telephoneResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getTel());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that `getAge()` and `getTel()` return String? Because I notice these are the only two that could be an int for instance. 
If not, cast it to String before calling `JTextComponent.setText(String t)`.

As for the `department`, there is not any instruction in your code to alter the text of this textfield...

Comment: Like you see on the picture the result of displaying departement is tn.esen.entites.departement (see the picture of my post) this what i write      departementResponsable.setText(responsableTechnique.getDepartement());
but i have this error the methode setText(string) in type Jtext..... is not applicable for the arguments departement

Comment: the instruction you are talking about `departementResponsable.setText(..)` is NOT in your initial code snippet.

In case you have put it and you get this error, this means that `responsableTechnique.getDepartement()` does not return a _String_ as expected from `setText(String s)`

Probably the same issue as `getAge()` and `getTel()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast those values into **String** before using it

```
ageFormattedTextField.setText(responsableTechnique.getAge() + "");
```

For the **Gender** field, it will depend on the way you filled your ComboBox elements. Can you post that code?

### Initialisation of Gender Combo

You can initialise your ComboBox like this

```
genreResponsable = new JComboBox(new String[] {"Homme","Femme"});
```

and then you can set its value like this

```
genreResponsable.setSelectedItem(responsableTechnique.getGenre());
```

Assuming that responsableTechnique.getGenre() returns a String value between `Homme` and `Femme`

Comment: here is the code of Gender   genreResponsable = new JComboBox();
   genreResponsable.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
  genreResponsable.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Homme","Femme"}));
  genreResponsable.setToolTipText("");
  genreResponsable.setBounds(247, 534, 141, 20);
  panel.add(genreResponsable);

Comment: Sorry but the Gender Combo didn't work i initilise it and i set genreResponsable.setSelectedItem(responsableTechnique.getGenre()); but it didn't work